# DLLImport C++ To .NET - char* (Pointer to string)

Tags: c++, casting, char

I am using a dll built using c++ in .NET (C#).
I am facing a problem with pointers to string (char*)

This is the function declaration in C++

```
EXPORT char* Read_Signal(char *Name)
{
     char* Info = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
     //more code
     return Info;
}
```

I tried DLLImport in these ways.

```
[DllImport("Com.dll", CallingConvertion = CallingConvertion.Cdecl)]
public static extern StringBuilder Read_Signal(StringBuilder Name);  => Not Working (crash)


[DllImport("Com.dll", CallingConvertion = CallingConvertion.Cdecl)]
public static extern string Read_Signal(string Name);  => Not Working (crash), I am not able to see the fail because no exception or message is shown, the application simply crashes. 


[DllImport("Com.dll", CallingConvertion = CallingConvertion.Cdecl)]
public static extern long Read_Signal(StreamBuilder Name);  => Works but the return long var is not useful (with int, char the call works but the response is obviously not useful).
```

Any idea for the right casting in the return value char* ?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: The better way to do this is make the C# code create the buffer, and all your function does is fill in the buffer.  Then the allocation of memory moves away from the C++ code to the C# client.  Then the return code need not be a `char *`, but maybe TRUE or FALSE or some value.

Comment: Thank you Paul. It's the way I've been doing it but unfortunately I don't have access to the code in C++ to modify the DLL in the appropriate way. I've trying a lot of conversions because importing this DLL in LabVIEW works perfectly. Sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Paul is correct - the usual way to structure C->C# string returns is to use a StringBuilder or other kind of buffer. This tiny snippet that I used for pulling window captions by hwnd conveniently works as an example of how to structure both C API and C# wrapper:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern long GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder lpString, long cch);

public static string GetWindowCaption(IntPtr hwnd) {
    var len = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(len + 1); // (count for \0 terminator)
    GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, len + 1);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```